# How to handle different views for different device orientations?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, orientation, nslayoutconstraint

I have a subview in portrait orientation (storyboard scene):

[image]

that I want to move and resize like this when the device rotates to landscape orientation:

[image]

What the best (or easiest) way to handle this should be?
I'm thinking about the following options:

1. Creating different separated `xib` files (one for portrait and another for landscape), and loading the corresponding one?
2. Rotating + translating + resizing the subview when orientation changes?
3. Directly creating both subviews (horizontal-bottom one, and vertical-left one) and hidding the corresponding according to the orientation?

I need help with this scenario, I don´t find a solution that works for me. Also if I'm missing any other option, I'll appreciate to know.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** This is an app targeting iOS 7 and above. I'm not using the size classes feature, just autolayout.

**EDIT 2:**

4. Setting a new frame to the subview.

What should be the difference of this option with option 2?

Comment: The UIPresentationController class is specifically designed for this as I understand it. However, I am not familiar enough with it to write a full answer. There are methods to allow for responding to size class changes which is what you would have here on some devices.

It is currently discouraged by Apple (I think) to make UI changes based on anything but size classes I believe and so if you want this behavior on the phones this may be nontrivial? I won't say for sure though.

Comment: @Braains Thanks for replying, I forgot to mention that I'm developing for iOS 7+ and I'm just using autolayout, I'm not taking advantage of size classes...

Comment: I think there's an easier solution to this. You can bind the view to left and bottom with superview. Next, take IBOutlet of view's height and width constraint. Change the value when the device rotates. If you want you can update constraint with animation too.. If you like the idea, let me know if you wanna know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Option (2) would be your best bet. Store two sets of constraints and install / uninstall them depending on the orientation. 
If you were using size classes, you could do this completely in IB.

(1) is overkill, and (3) is unnecessary.

In portrait mode you have the following constraints for your subview:

- Horizontal space constraints for the left, right sides
- A vertical space constraint for the bottom side
- A height constraint

After the device is rotated to the landscape orientation, you'll change the constraints so that you'll end up with the following constraints for your subview:

- Vertical space constraints for the top and bottom sides
- A horizontal space constraint for the left side
- A width constraint

Comment: Thank you too. After a rotation, how the constraints are affected?

Comment: They aren't affected. The new location each view will have after the rotation will be computed according to the same constraints. If you want the views to have a different location after an orientation change, then you have to update your constraints accordingly. See my updated answer to find out how